# How do I make a website work so that "index.html" does not appear on my home page's link after the website name?

Tags: html, web-hosting

After uploading to a web hosting service, my home page has a name as follows: `example.com/index.html`
Is there any way that I can change the `index.html` in the link to "home" or something else? I am using Bluehost if that helps.

Comment: You will need to configure url rewriting on your hosting provider, i don't know bluehost so i cant give you more details, but i guess in their backend somewhere you can configure the url rewrite, depending on the server used like apache or nginx

Comment: I don’t think that’s necessary. `index.html` is the default for _directory index_ files, meaning if you open a URl pointing to `/` the webserver will deliver index.html already. The key is to not produce links pointing to /index.html but to / only. So it completely depends on your HTML usually, and you did not share how that is produced. It all depends on that.

Comment: Yes, as Andy mentioned index.html will be your default page when your domain is accessed.  Try giving your home page  link as `/` or  `your-domain.com` . Does its show any error? If not working you can easily fix it using a `.htaccess` file if your webserver supports it.

Answer (score -1):

`index.html` is designed to never show up in URLs to users.  `index.html` is the document powers requests for the directory.  If `index.html` is showing up in your URLs, that usually means that you are linking to the home page incorrectly.

#### Modify your links:

- `<a href=http://example.com/index.html>` → `<a href=http://example.com/>`
- `<a href=/index.html>` → `<a href=/>`
- `<a href=index.html>` → `<a href=./>`

Of those, I would suggest using `<a href=/>` to link to our home page. That is a site-relative link to your home page.  It will work on any page on your site, regardless of how deep in directories it is. Unlike absolute links, it is easy to use the same code on a live server and on a staging server.